# how to check if one column field data is null then check other field that same row laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am Retrieve Data  From MySQL Database, where the condition is if the checking out data field is null then check the send field to that particular row

```
id   |  SSC | hhc |  dip
1    |  50  | 50  | null
2    |  60  | null| 60
3    |  50  | 55  | null
```

condition is "hhc" and "dip" are not both null and they are not both fill up at one time

i realy don't know what to do
i try

```
$users->where('student_masters.hhc','>=' ,60);
$users->where('student_masters.dip','>=' ,60);
```

i retrive all data but condition is `if('student_masters.hhc' == null)` then check the other field means `student_masters.dip` 
please help me what i do

Comment: thanks for reply but,this is but problem is that one row it have "hhc" but when we are in second row it "hhc" value is null on that time we consider the "dip" value

Comment: your question is not clear, please elaborate. include your database schema and your laravel controller. please try to rephrase what you are trying to do, and include any errors you see.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('student_masters.hhc','!=' ,null);
        $q->where('student_masters.dip','=' ,null);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($q) {
        $q->where('student_masters.hhc','=' ,null);
        $q->where('student_masters.dip','!=' ,null);
    })
```

This may help you. though question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pull the value of either column and don't care which one it came from, you could use a MySQL case statement.  That will allow you to use the value of dip if hhc is null.

```
$users->select( DB::raw("CASE WHEN hhc IS NULL THEN dip ELSE hhc END AS data_value") )->get();
```

Note that we're using a raw select statement here as there is no way to do this with pure query builder.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html